# clinfo returning segmentation error

Tags: intel, gpu, opencl

When I run clinfo, I get a seg fault. I tried reinstalling OpenCL, but it did not help. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 if it makes any difference.

I also get a -1 error on clGetDeviceIDs.

```
  Platform Name                                   Clover
Number of devices                                 0

  Platform Name                                   Intel(R) OpenCL HD Graphics
Number of devices                                 1
  Device Name                                     Intel(R) Gen9 HD Graphics NEO
  Device Vendor                                   Intel(R) Corporation
  Device Vendor ID                                0x8086
  Device Version                                  OpenCL 2.1 NEO 
  Driver Version                                  19.06.12357
  Device OpenCL C Version                         OpenCL C 2.0 
  Device Type                                     GPU
  Device Profile                                  FULL_PROFILE
  Max compute units                               24
  Max clock frequency                             1000MHz
  Device Partition                                (core)
    Max number of sub-devices                     0
    Supported partition types                     None
  Max work item dimensions                        3
  Max work item sizes                             256x256x256
  Max work group size                             256
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Please help.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! A segmentation fault usually means a bug. Please see [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to get some more details about what went wrong if you run the program through valgrind, like this:

```
valgrind clinfo
```